# Glitchy Coloring in Render view

Tags: 3d-view

[image]I'm new to blender and I'm following a tutorial from YouTube. I've noticed weird color issues while in render scene and I wanted to know if someone could explain to me what is happening. I don't know much about 3D software but I do know that they consume lots of GPU ram.  I'm not too sure about the preferences like with photoshop so I only tweaked the memory consumption from 4GB to 8Gb but its only utilizing (as of now), 500MB.

**TLDR: Random pixels in Render Scene.**

From blender these specs meet the minimum requirement

My PC specs - Intel HD graphics 620 (integrated)
- 16GB RAM
- Intel I5 7200U 2.7~3.1Ghz**

Comment: 1) This is not a memory issue. 2) what is the material for the sparkling plane?

Comment: This is an common eevee issue,I don't know the solution yet but using cycles helps

Comment: It's most likely a graphics card problem - meaning, it glitches because you don't have one. Here are the minimum specs : https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: @Rajjaiswal. Thanks, Changing to Cycles actually pixilated the cube but looks a lot better. Workbench render engine seems to work best for me so I'll stick with that.

Comment: Well,it did not pixelated it. Actually it was still rendering in the viewport. Cycles is a much heavier render engine hence takes time to render. Using workbench is good if it makes the work done but keep in mind that workbench can never ever give things like shadows,textures and most importantly,photorealism.

Comment: Pixelate wasn't exactly what I meant because only when I panned around to look at the the preview it started distorting into a pixelated way that wasn't nice to look at. Other than that it worked fine.